# Nginx redirect www http to non-www https causing host name mismatch certificate error in Safari

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, safari

I am trying to redirect http://www.example.com to https://example.com. Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     www.example.com;
        return          301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     example.com;
        return          301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen          443 ssl;

        root            /var/www/example.com;
        index           index.php;
        server_name     example.com;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

[...]

}
```

I have also tried a similar configuration in which the second server block is listening on port 443 instead of port 80. Both the mentioned configurations yield the expected result in Firefox and Chrome, but Safari throws a scary "This certificate is not valid (host name mismatch)" warning box for the user, which I do not want.

I am not using a wildcard SSL certificate but rather I am trying to get by with just a single domain certificate (valid for example.com). Is what I'm trying to do possible with a single domain SSL certificate?

Comment: Is Safari fail only with redirects? If you type https://example.com in address bar - what happens?

Comment: example.com in Safari yields a redirect to https://example.com with no certificate error.